# Rename table in Postgres and update its usages in all functions

Tags: postgresql, rename

I need to safely rename a table and be sure, that all usages of this table in functions are also renamed.

Example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
    id serial,
    name varchar(255)
);

CREATE FUNCTION public.last_test() RETURNS SETOF test
    LANGUAGE sql STABLE
AS $$
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      test
    LIMIT 10;
$$;

ALTER TABLE test RENAME TO tests;
```

Now, when I look into function `last_test`, I see, that it still references old `test` table name.

Is it even possible to rename a table and all it's usages in functions automatically?

Comment: Think about `CREATE VIEW new_name SELECT * FROM old_name`. *and be sure, that all usages of this table in functions are also renamed* It's close to impossible in general case. Imagine that the function uses dynamic SQL where the table name is built dynamically based on some data...

Comment: This one simple function is just for example. I have many functions, that creating instances and setting up some related data. These functions are still using old table name. Where is a problem in this case? Storage method of function's source code in plain text instead of database objects? If so, maybe some refactoring extensions are existing?